# How can I override _document.js in Next.js 13 with 'src/' directory created through create-next-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

_document.js ignored by NextJs

I created a project with npx create-next-app in

- plain js
- with the `src/` directory
- Using App Router

I want to override my _document.js.

I followed the [official guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-document) but:
My first doubt is that I don't have a /pages folder, probably (?) because I replied yes to Use the src directory.

So I created the folder and the file under `src/pages/_document.js` and pasted the override from nodejs docs changing the language.

`<Html lang="it">` 
Refreshing the page I still see 'en', and putting a breakpoint it is not getting hitted.

I tried to remove the .next folder and run npm dev again, but no luck next is still ignoring that file.

How do I override _document in nextjs 13 in an application bootstrapped with create-react-app with the src/ folder?

Update:
Changed folder structure as suggested by @Deng Won
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riv6f.png)

Comment: The last line (update) could be easely overseen. Could you just answer your own question and mark it as solved? I was searching for this answer for the last hour and could've missed it easely (thankfully not).